# Plotting dendrogram from vegan::meandist() in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, cluster-analysis, dendrogram, vegan

Vegan::meandist() has a really nice plot method that creates a dendrogram of the mean dissimilarities. How can I incorporate the output into ggplot to have full control over the aesthetics? Here is some sample code using Dune. As an example, I'd like to recreate the dendrogram in ggplot and color each Management level by 'Use' (see factors in Dune.env).

```
# Species and environmental data
require(vegan)

dune <- read.delim ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zdealveindy/anadat-r/master/data/dune2.spe.txt', row.names = 1)

dune.env <- read.delim ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zdealveindy/anadat-r/master/data/dune2.env.txt', row.names = 1)

data(dune) 
data(dune.env)

dune_dist <- vegdist(dune, method = "bray", na.rm=T)

dissim <- meandist(dune_dist, grouping = dune.env$Management) 

plot(dissim)
```

Comment: Each `Management` level has several `Use` levels how would you handle the situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`?vegan:::plot.meandist`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/vegan/versions/2.4-2/topics/mrpp) it is clear `hclust` function is used for `kind = "dendrogram"`. To recreate:

```
zz <- hclust(as.dist(dissim), method = "average") #use desired method, "average" is the default in vegan:::plot.meandist
```

Now to visualize the tree using ggplot:

```
library(ggdendro)
```

create a data.frame from the tree:

```
dd <- as.dendrogram(zz) 
dd <- dendro_data(zz)
```

get the diagonal elements from the dissimilarity matrix since they represent within-cluster variability (see @Jari Oksanens comments bellow):

```
data.frame(diag = diag(dissim)) %>%
  rownames_to_column("label") -> dissim_diag

dissim_diag
  label      diag
1    BF 0.4159972
2    HF 0.4418115
3    NM 0.6882438
4    SF 0.5813015
```

now there is a need to change segment data so the leaves do not end at 0 but at the appropriate distance.

```
segment(dd) 
       x         y xend      yend
1  1.875 0.7412760 1.00 0.7412760
2  1.000 0.7412760 1.00 0.0000000
3  1.875 0.7412760 2.75 0.7412760
4  2.750 0.7412760 2.75 0.5960416
5  2.750 0.5960416 2.00 0.5960416
6  2.000 0.5960416 2.00 0.0000000
7  2.750 0.5960416 3.50 0.5960416
8  3.500 0.5960416 3.50 0.4736637
9  3.500 0.4736637 3.00 0.4736637
10 3.000 0.4736637 3.00 0.0000000
11 3.500 0.4736637 4.00 0.4736637
12 4.000 0.4736637 4.00 0.0000000
```

In other words where x is a whole number and yend is 0 we need to change the yend to the appropriate distance. The following code accomplishes this in two joins. First join adds the `label(dd)` data and the second join adds `dissim_diag` data to the segment data:

```
segment_data <- segment(dd) %>%
  left_join(
    label(dd),
    by = c("xend" = "x",
           "yend" = "y")) %>%
  left_join(dissim_diag) %>%
  mutate(yend = pmax(yend, diag, na.rm = TRUE)) #use as yend whichever is higher yend or diag, ignoring NA.

segment_data
       x         y xend      yend label      diag
1  1.875 0.7412760 1.00 0.7412760  <NA>        NA
2  1.000 0.7412760 1.00 0.6882438    NM 0.6882438
3  1.875 0.7412760 2.75 0.7412760  <NA>        NA
4  2.750 0.7412760 2.75 0.5960416  <NA>        NA
5  2.750 0.5960416 2.00 0.5960416  <NA>        NA
6  2.000 0.5960416 2.00 0.5813015    SF 0.5813015
7  2.750 0.5960416 3.50 0.5960416  <NA>        NA
8  3.500 0.5960416 3.50 0.4736637  <NA>        NA
9  3.500 0.4736637 3.00 0.4736637  <NA>        NA
10 3.000 0.4736637 3.00 0.4159972    BF 0.4159972
11 3.500 0.4736637 4.00 0.4736637  <NA>        NA
12 4.000 0.4736637 4.00 0.4418115    HF 0.4418115
```

A similar manipulation is needed to create appropriate label cooridnates:

```
text_data <- label(dd) %>%
  left_join(dissim_diag) %>%
  mutate(y = diag,
         group = factor(rep(c("one", "two"),  2))) #just some random groups to color by
```

Now the actual plot:

```
ggplot(segment_data) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = x,
                   y = y,
                   xend = xend,
                   yend = yend))  +
  theme_dendro() + 
  theme(axis.line.y = element_line(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_line(),
        axis.text.y = element_text()) +
  geom_text(aes(x = x,
                y = y,
                label = label,
                color = group),
            angle = -90, hjust = 0,
            data = text_data)
```

[image]

Kudos to @Jari Oksanens for his comments!

Comment: Amazing solution! However I can't figure out how to display the dissimilarity scores (height) as the scale on the tree. Setting theme_dendrogram() displays a scale that is not the actual dissimilarity values in zz$height

Comment: @Joshua Smith please see edits and post a comment if something is not clear or working as intened.

Comment: I'd really like to see how do this in ggplot2 graphics, but this does not do the same as `vegan:::plot.meandist(..., kind="dendro")`: the "hang" or the length of the vertical terminal segments should be adapted so that the height of the label shows the within-cluster variability. In vegan this was solved by drawing dendrogram with hang=0 (no terminal vertical), and drawing these lines separately with `segments`. In this example the terminal segments should end at (left to right) 0.688, 0.581, 0.416, 0.442.

Comment: It seems that ggtree handles phylo trees with have branch lengths. So you need to find those branch lengths. vegan:::plot.meandist has example code to find the needed numbers. For result object `dismiss`, the tips (in ggtree terminology) should be at `diag(dismiss)` and code uses `dendrapply` to find the heights from which you draw vertical segment to the tip, and their difference is the terminal branch length.

Comment: @Jari Oksanen could you please check if the figure is correct now?

Comment: @missuse looks good. A bit tricky to do: things are so much easier without ggplot. Here a [man page with graphics](https://vegandevs.github.io/vegan/reference/mrpp.html) for comparison (second graph).

Answer (score 0):

The [dendextend](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/index.html) package was designed to assist with such tasks (and it is based on code from ggdendro - it is a more flexible and simple-to-us codebase at this point than ggdendro).
You can see a section on ggplot2 integration in [the vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/vignettes/dendextend.html#ggplot2-integration).

Because of issues with my own computer (old linux mint), I can't install vegan to reproduce your example.
But if I use similar data, here is an example of usage:

```
dune <- read.delim ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zdealveindy/anadat-r/master/data/dune2.spe.txt', row.names = 1)
dune.env <- read.delim ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zdealveindy/anadat-r/master/data/dune2.env.txt', row.names = 1)
dissim <- dist(dune) # a hack, just because I can't get vegan to work
zz <- hclust(as.dist(dissim), method = "average") #use desired method, "average" is the default in vegan:::plot.meandist
```

The code to get a dendrogram:

```
library(dendextend)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(as.dendrogram(zz))
```

Output (again, not the same analysis as above, but you can use your own code to fix it)

[image]

This also supports coloring of branches, labels, rotations, and more.
You can go to [the vignette here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/vignettes/dendextend.html), to learn more.

Comment: vegan can be installed in any sound Linux system (i.e., having R build tools).